# Keeping opened tab order in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I like to have my opened tab clearly ordered: `.h` next to corresponding `.cpp`, file grouped by theme, and so on.

My customized order is always messed by visual studio. For example, I have 6 files opened. I open a new one, and put it on a split view on the right. The task bar on the left in now too small to show all 6 files. Ok. But when I will close the right pane you can be sure that the order of the files in the left pane has been messed up, and now I don't remember were each file is.

Is there a solution to that? An extension to group tabs, maybe? I try to use new windows, never resize split windows, but visual will always end up messing their order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension to group and order tabs.